# Reactjs, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to make Searchbar where I can fetch the authors and show the author Id and picture, Why I'm getting this error in my code:

> any Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'never'

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Searchbar() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // Add one more state to store the authors being searched for

  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list`);
      setData(res.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(
      data.filter((authorData) =>
        authorData['author'].toLowerCase().includes(query)
      )
    );
  }, [query, data]);

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <input
        className='search'
        placeholder='Search...'
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
      />
      <div>
        {searchResults.map((author) => (
          <div>{author}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Searchbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be you are relying on typescript to infer types of an api call. (Instead typescript inferred it as `never` which would always error if you try anything with it)

To fix this, simply set a type for the fetch data

```
type fetchData = {
  id: number,
  author: string,
  width: number,
  height: number,
  url: string,
  download_url: string
}
```

Then set your states as such

```
const [data, setData] = useState<fetchData[]>([]);
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<fetchData[]>([]);
```

Full code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

type fetchData = {
  id: number,
  author: string,
  width: number,
  height: number,
  url: string,
  download_url: string
}

function Searchbar() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const [data, setData] = useState<fetchData[]>([]);

  // Add one more state to store the authors being searched for

  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<fetchData[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list`);
      setData(res.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(
      data.filter((authorData : fetchData) =>
        authorData.author.toLowerCase().includes(query)
      )
    );
  }, [query, data]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <input
        className="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
      />
      <div>
        {searchResults.map((author) => (
          <div key={author.id}>{author.author}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Searchbar;
```

Comment: that works,  thank you, one other thing. the Author's name is it possible that it shows only when I type in search bar. The Authors name shouldn't be showing on the page?

Comment: You might need to use a button and once the button is clicked then it will set the query string.